# Best practices for add/editing forms in lit-html/lit-element

Tags: javascript, lit-element, lit-html

I have a rather complex form, and would like to make sure it works both in editing and as a "new record" form.
The form's submit is actually prevented, and JSON is actually sent over. However, this is besides the point.
Also, `this.record` is assigned on load (for editing) and an empty object for new records.

```
render () {
  return html`
    <form>
      <input type="text" .value="${this.record.description}">
      <input type="text" .value="${this.record.remarks}">
    </form>
  `
}
```

The idea is that if the form is rendered, and there is data in this.record, it will have the data pre-populated.

This assumes that this.record doesn't change under the form's butt -- if it does, the user input WILL be overwritten.

Is what I described above best practice? Or is it best NOT to use `.value=` and assign the fields by hand on load?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to be aware of here. I'm going to assume that `this.record` is an observed property (or has an `@property` decorator).

Firstly, changes to `this.record.property` *won't* cause a refresh. LitElement checks for equality but on objects it's checking the reference - you'll have to call `requestUpdate` directly to cause a re-render.

Secondly, if you change the value of an input LitElement won't compare to the current DOM value, but to the assigned value. If you want to compare against the DOM value use [`live`](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#live). You can use this to ensure that changes to `this.record` don't update the DOM when the value added is the same.

In situations like this, where I need to submit a form or JSON to actually make a change, I use two objects - one representing the value from the server (with TS `Readonly<T>` constraints or [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to make sure I don't mutate it) and different one holding user changes that I can send back to the server. Then when a render happens I know what's changed (and can show that).